# How to fetch data from the database in Django on clicking submit?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I need to get database objects on the HTML only when the the SUBMIT is clicked and not on page load. I currently have an AJAX script running on the same form where it returns the text entered in textbox onto the HTML when submit is clicked. I want this feature to stay as well as add a new feature of retrieval of data. Below are some of the code snippets I am using:

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def chat(request):
    resps   = Responses.objects.all()
    context = {'resps' : resps}
    return render(request, "chat.html", context)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('chat/', views.chat,  name='chat'),
```

**chat.html**

```
<form id="testForm" name="test-form" class="test-form" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <input id="texting" name="texting" type="text" class="test-text" placeholder="Test here"/>
  <div class="footer">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
</div>
{% for r in resps %}
<div>
  <p>{{r.response}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}

................................................

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('submit','#testForm', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          type  : 'POST',
          url   : '/chat/',
          data  :{
            text : $('#texting').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[text=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
          },
          success : function(){
            // alert("Done!");
            document.getElementById("userSpeaks").innerHTML = document.getElementById('texting').value;
          }
        });
      });
  </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I just need a way out to print the model objects on each click of the submit button and not automatically on page load. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in `char()` you could remove `resps  = Responses.objects.all()` and when you click button you could execute other function which uses `resps  = Responses.objects.all()` and send it to browser. `$.ajax({ url: '/other_function_to_get_data/', ...` OR use `if request.method == 'POST':` to recognize if you load it as `GET` or you clicked button and send `POST`. For `GET` you can send full HTML with form but for `POST` you can send data in JSON format and JavaScript can add to existing `HTML`

Answer (score 2):

Please change the line

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[text=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
```

to

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

So you will have to send your querylist as a json object if you want it to be sent through ajax

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core.serializers import serialize

@csrf_exempt
def chat(request):
    data = {
            'resps': serialize("json", Responses.objects.all())
        }
        
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

and you `success` will look something like this

```
success : function(data){
            // alert("Done!");
            resps = JSON.parse(data.resps);
            var htmldata=""
            for(var x in resps){
            htmldata+="<p>"+resps[x].fields.xyz+"</p>"
            }


            $("#userSpeaks").html(htmldata);
          }
```