# Send Email with Django to contact

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send a templated email to a contact saved in a database. How can pre enter the email detail of the contact and remove the forms. I have tried to replace `recipient = str(sub['Email'].value())` by `recipient = str(sub['lead.id'].value())` but it didn`t work.

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def subscribe(request, lead_id):
    lead = Lead.objects.get(pk=lead_id)
    sub = forms.Subscribe()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sub = forms.Subscribe(request.POST)
        subject = 'Introduction'
        message = 'Good morning,'
        recipient = str(sub['Email'].value())
        send_mail(subject, 
            message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recipient], fail_silently = False)
        return render(request, 'subscribe/success.html', {'recipient': recipient, 'lead': lead})
    return render(request, 'subscribe/index.html', {'form':sub, 'lead': lead})
```

**forms.py**

```
class Subscribe(forms.Form):
    Email = forms.EmailField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Email
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<lead_id>[0-9]+)/subscribe$', views.subscribe, name='subscribe'),
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to have a non-editable email input field with its value provided by you from the backend?

Comment: I`ve got a contact list with email and phone number. Each contact got the name, phone and email. I would like to click on the detail of the contact and be able to send an email to this contact. I want to remove the form. The recipient needs to be taken from contact list itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all your Contacts on the index page with their names between anchor tags and href as url to subscribe with a parameter lead_id as persons id

lets say you sent the context to index page as `contacts`

```
{% for i in contacts%}

<a href='{% url 'subscribe' lead_id=i.id  %}'> {{i.name}}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

Now inside your subscribe function

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def subscribe(request, lead_id):
    lead = Lead.objects.get(pk=lead_id)
    subject = 'Introduction'
    message = 'Good morning,'
    recipient = lead.email
    send_mail(subject, 
        message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recipient], fail_silently = False)
        
    return render(request, 'subscribe/success.html', {'recipient': recipient, 'lead': lead})
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works. Can we show a success modal or message instead a html page?

Comment: Yeah..you can use ajax for that...and activate a modal once u get success.Refer this ques to see how to use ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796023/how-to-fetch-data-from-the-database-in-django-on-clicking-submit